# why putting function inside forwardRef solves this error

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref, forward-reference

currently I was facing this error

```
forwardRef render functions do not support propTypes or defaultProps. Did you accidentally pass a React component?
```

any way by googling, I found solution for this, which is putting function declaration inside 'forwardRef'.

```
//this code generates 
const Button = (props, ref) => {return ...Component}

Button.propTypes ={...}

return forwardRef(Button)
```

```
// by this way, no error happens
const Button = forwardRef(function Button(props, ref){return ...Component})

Button.propTypes ={...}

return Button
```

Glad the error got solved, but I just can't understand why this method solved the error..

anybody have idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you can only add propTypes if it is a React Component. However, this Button is not a react component because of the second parameter **ref** (i.e. React Components only have one parameter which is **props**. So here you cannot add propTypes, hence the error.

```
const Button = (props, ref) => {return ...Component}

Button.propTypes ={...}

return forwardRef(Button)
```

Now this code works, because the forwardRef function, takes in props, ref and returns a React Component. In a React component, you can add propTypes.
Which is why it works.

```
// by this way, no error happens
const Button = forwardRef(function Button(props, ref){return ...Component})

Button.propTypes ={...}

return Button
```

Hope this helps